# Why Oracle OFFSET and LIMIT is not working when using DISTINCT

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to get clarified the below situation.

I have a city, country table and I need to validate this will some other tables and get the city country results ordered by the country. Here's my query for that

```
SELECT distinct
c.code                as CITY ,
c.country             as COUNTRY from location_info li
inner join someTable     s   on li.loc_id = s.some_id
inner join city          c   on s.city         = c.code
ORDER BY c.country
```

And this provides the results as

[image]

Now when I use OFFSET and LIMIT values in the below query

```
SELECT distinct
c.code                as CITY,
c.country             as COUNTRY from location_info li
inner join someTable     s   on li.loc_id = s.some_id
inner join city          c   on s.city         = c.code
ORDER BY c.country OFFSET 5 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY.
```

I expect to get `ADOR, ADPC, ADSJ, ADVD, ALV` as the output.

[image]

Why is that and what I am missing here in this query.

When I do the following I get the expected outcome

```
SELECT CITY, COUNTRY FROM ( SELECT distinct
c.code                as CITY,
c.country             as COUNTRY from location_info li
inner join someTable     s   on li.loc_id = s.some_id
inner join city          c   on s.city         = c.code
ORDER BY c.country ) OFFSET 5 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY.
```

Comment: Please show us the exact output you are getting in all cases (note: there should be _two_ columns per record, as you are selecting two columns).  The issue here is distinct.

Comment: Are you only ordering by the country but looking at ordering of the city? Maybe you just need to add `, city` to the `order by` clause.

Comment: The result set has two columns, but you are showing only one of them (the country). Can you show boh columns?

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Look at the explanation for AskTom site, https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9541036000346055103 ..when the column used in order by clause contains duplicate value....and as hint from @Jon Heller..add `city` to `order by` and you will have your expected result

Comment: I removed the `oracle10g` tag as that didn't support `offset` or `fetch next`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the `ORDER BY` is not *stable*.  What that means is that you have ties in the key values.  So, running the query two times might result in different orderings.

This is easily fixed by including more keys in the `order by` so the `order by` keys uniquely identify each row:

```
select distinct c.code as CITY, c.country as COUNTRY
from location_info li join
     someTable s
     on li.loc_id = s.some_id join
     city c
     on s.city  = c.code
order by c.country, c.code;
```

Comment: This works, But if `ORDER BY` is not stable, then how come the second query provides the expected outcome? ( I am asking about the query where I have used parentheses to isolate the inner query )

Comment: @Klaus . . . That is the issue with ties in the data.  Sometimes things work the way you expect; sometimes they do not.